# Is it correct to write "this book discusses"?

Tags: verbs, is-it-a-rule, animacy

I often see people write the following:

> this book will discuss...

or

> this paper has discussed...

I once wrote in a paper in English class that had the sentence: "this article discusses..." My teacher told me this is wrong explaining that people discuss things, not articles or papers.

Was my teacher correct, or is it fine to write

> this paper will discuss ...?

It's something I see fairly often.

Comment: I think that any teacher who insists that one should avoid 'discusses' is in the same league as those who insist that you can only use possessives with animates (the leg of the chair v. the chair's leg) and complain about the death of adverbs. Just ignore them and their bleating and use 'this paper will discuss.' (I would suggest that you write 'in this paper, I will discuss...', but in my experience purists like your teacher are also against I/we in formal writing. So just do what your teacher wants and complain about it under your breath)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a peeve

Comment: @FF I CV-ed on 'no reasonable research given' ('A quick google search offered the below and similar definitions' actually appears in an answer below); I don't know how these votes disappear (or why they aren't echoed). // Hello, Pame. Please take the tour of ELU, and add research (where possible) in future.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure I can see your point. But in that case the vast majority of questions here would be unnecessary because you could find answers to them with through research. Instead of making research myself I instead went here and asked a straightforward question which had not been asked before, and got useful answers which will be useful to others in the future as well. Isn't that a lot of the point of this forum? I think it is quite damaging to this forum when people are made to feel bad for asking questions relevant to the theme of the site. Consequently probably won't post here again.

Comment: @Pame I wouldn't be discouraged by a Close Vote. Your question was reopened and it is normal to have divergence of opinions. The value of the site is also increased by this factor. Be welcome!

Comment: You've skewed what I said, Pam: 'no reasonable research given' not 'thorough research not given'. ELU is aimed at linguists, not those with more basic questions. If you look at a few other questions, you will see that (I'm guessing) most of those where it is possible show some results of basic research, even if it's negative like 'Collins and AHD do not list this sense'. The 'lack of research' close-vote is seen as a _plus_ of the site.

Comment: Your teacher is simply quite wrong.  As this QA discusses in detail. And this is an excellent question, thanks for asking.

Comment: Hi @Pame This is an excellent question.  You can ignore the complaints above.  :)   Awesome answers here too BTW.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is "my teacher told me" not showing research?

Comment: Related question on Academia: [Is the personification of concepts or terms accepted in academic writing?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/147818/7734)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No. When a quick check in one of the readily available respectable online dictionaries will perhaps provide an answer, the provision of such evidence (even say 'Collins, AHD and Cambridge Dictionary do not carry this sense') is expected on ELU. You can check this on ELU.Meta. Unaccompanied anecdotal evidence (hardly easily ratifiable) is only very rarely the way to go.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When it means *to deal with* or *treat* a subject, ***discuss*** does not need an animate subject. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discuss) explains that *discuss* can mean:

> to treat (a subject) in speech or writing
>
> - The first three *volumes **discuss*** basic principles.

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=discuss) also agrees, defining *discuss as meaning*:

> To examine or consider (a subject) in speech or writing:
>
> - *The book **discusses*** the challenges that journalists face today.

In the same way you can say that *an article or book **argues**, **debates** or **disputes***. There are plenty of such examples, so I don't see why your teacher is strict in using this structure. Even if you do correct the sentence according to your teacher's recommendation,  keep in mind that it is nevertheless correct.

Comment: As described in Sebastian E's answer, these definitions depend on [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), whereby one concept (the volumes, the book) is used to refer to a related concept (the author[s] thereof).

Comment: +1, and a bit of tactical advice: if you run into a teacher like this, just say "oops! you're right, thank you for catching that", change it in that paper and subsequent papers in their class, and ignore it outside of that class. In other words: the teacher is wrong, but it's easier to just pretend they're right for their class.

Comment: @yshavit:  NOO!  Pull out the dictionary and show it to them!

Answer (score 11):

While examples from dictionaries with inanimate objects were provided, it could be argued that a book (or any other inanimate object) can not really "discuss". However, it's idiomatic and "Book" can be understood as a metonymy for the author(s).

*[The Metonymy of AUTHOR for TEXT](https://books.openedition.org/chbeck/1621?lang=de)* provides an in-detail historical discussion that enables AUTHORS to be read, instead of their texts.

Another closely related example for a metonymy that enables a "book" to do something (progress) would be "Product for process: This is a type of metonymy where the product of the activity stands for the activity itself. For example, in "The **book is moving** right along," the book refers to the process of writing or publishing." ([Lakoff and Johnson 1999, p. 203](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy#cite_note-22))

The "White House", e.g., can also not do many things it regularly does since it's a house.

If you look at the definition of "to discuss" in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discuss): "If you discuss something, you write or talk about it in detail." with example "I will discuss the role of diet in cancer prevention in Chapter 7". Depending on who you ask, personal pronouns are a no-go in scientific literature, so using a metonymy helps.

Comment: Just to be argumentative: what if the article was written by ChatGPT?

Comment: Ist ChatGBT just a metonomy?

Comment: diet can prevent cancer ?

Comment: That depends, of course, on whether there is an example to be found that prevent may be used as such in any of the available dictionaries.

Comment: What is the meaning of the capitalisations "AUTHOR" and "TEXT" (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: What would ChatGPT be a metonomy for? When I publish a paper, the statements in the paper are things that I (or one of my co-authors, all of who are human beings like me) deliberately chose to say. In contrast, one of the warnings on ChatGPT's site is that it may write things that are offensive, which presumably all of the actual people involved in the creation and running of ChatGPT would know better than to write. Of course whatever ChatGPT writes is somehow a composite of sequences of words written by real humans, but if this is "metonomy" then I wonder what "metonomy" really means.

Comment: Similar "misuses" of verbs occur throughout English "the house stands on a small hill" ... a house can't stand; it doesn't have feet. "the road winds up the mountain" ... the road is stationary ... it can't move, so how can it wind? If you argue this way, you end up invalidating an immense number of common English constructions.

Comment: @PeterShor Are you suggesting that "discuss" is not a metonymy here?

Comment: Is *stand* a metonymy in *the house stands on the hill*? I don't think so, and I don't think *discusses* is here, either.

Comment: I like your answer ... I also don't think that house is a metonymy in the house stands on the hill since I don't see any possible substitution.

Answer (score 7):

This is presumably not the main point of your question, but I would not write, as you suggest, "this paper will discuss" unless the paper has yet to be written. Simply say "this paper discusses" if it already exists. Likewise you would not normally use the past tense unless you are emphasising that a work predates one being discussed in the present (e.g. "Paper A discusses using left-handed widgets for this purpose. Paper B had previously considered right-handed widgets.").

Comment: +1. I edit STEM manuscripts for the Elsevier and Springer–Nature journal families, and this is consistent with their internal style guides. [You can go a long way in the present tense.](http://john.maloney.org/Editing/present_tense.htm)

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search offered the below and similar definitions. It is also something you often hear, so I don't think you could emphatically say it is incorrect to do so in formal writing, either.

> **[discuss](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discuss)**
>
> To talk or write about a subject in detail, especially considering
> different ideas and opinions related to it:
> ***The later chapters discuss** the effects on the environment*.

(dictionary.cambridge.org)

Comment: The question is about "the book" talking, writing, discussing, etc.

Comment: The standard English is always "book below", not "below book", although the latter is common among non-native writers.

Answer (score 1):

**The TLDR is that there's nothing wrong with your usage**, as others here have argued. A number of responses have shown that using discuss metaphorically is widely accepted. That means professional writers, English experts, and average people likely use it all the time. Should you use it in class? Why poke the bear; go along and get along. But outside of class, feel free.

Teachers generally have good intentions. But teachers are often poorly educated.

There is a certain tension as a teacher between directing students to use language clearly to help them communicate and get a job, and just giving them rules that are either passed down or are personal pet peeves that have nothing to do with helping the student. While the latter category isn't really worth discussing, the former is. Here is a [list of common misconceptions about English language usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_English_usage_misconceptions). The current use of English possessive with "'s" started out as a misconception amusingly enough.

That makes it tough for a student to know which rules are rules worth keeping, and which aren't. For instance, I fastidiously observe the subjunctive use of were, but many people do not. "Were you to remember the detail, it would be useful to share it." Often time, the choices of rules you follow often identify you with a group of people, and sometimes one group has more power and influence. In linguistics, this is called [prestige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics)).

Develop your own style, and keep paying attention to criticisms and weighing them. If you're serious about writing, then you might want to pay attention to the famous psycholinguist Steven Pinker who has taken a look at English rules and has his own analysis of them in [*The Sense of Style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sense_of_Style). It's contemporaneous and rooted in cognitive research and builds upon Strunk and White and others.

Answer (score -2):

The poster’s teacher was correct if he was attempting to instil in him a critical attitude to language. In education we learn the norm and then later learn that there are deviations from it. If you try to do it any other way the student will go mad.

Once the student (poster) becomes mature enough in his intellectual outlook to accept this, then he can observe how language is used and decide for himself what he prefers, according to the context and audience, without insisting that his decision is “correct”.

For what it’s worth, I would avoid “the book discusses” myself if possible. But it’s not worth a lot to anyone except me.

N.B.
This general principle assumes that, as in this case, there is no ambiguity in alternative expressions. If a journalist in the Financial Times writes “genetic code” instead of “genome” I feel like strangling her.